# [kinetic actionlib]no matching function for call ac.sendGoal(goal);

Tags: ros-kinetic, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use actionlib to control ur3.I write the problem according to the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/descartes/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20Descartes.
The difference is that my server is execute_trajectory. So i change the code in the function of exexutetrajectory as the following :

```
    bool executeTrajectory(const trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory& trajectory)
{
  // Create a Follow Joint Trajectory Action Client
  actionlib::SimpleActionClient<moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryAction> ac("execute_trajectory", true);

  if (!ac.waitForServer(ros::Duration(2.0)))
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Could not connect to action server");
    return false;
  }

  moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryActionGoal goal;
  //goal.goal.trajectory.joint_trajectory = trajectory;
  //goal.goal_time_tolerance = ros::Duration(1.0);




 ac.sendGoal(goal);

  //if (ac.waitForResult(goal.trajectory.points[goal.trajectory.points.size()-1].time_from_start + ros::Duration(5)))
  //{
  //  ROS_INFO("Action server reported successful execution");
    //return true;
  //} else {
    //ROS_WARN("Action server could not execute trajectory");
    //return false;
  //}
}
```

i can't figure out what's the problem of my code,.when i catkin_make the code, the output of the terminal is:

```
/home/lkj/catkin_ws/src/move_group_test/src/cartesian.cpp: In function ‘bool executeTrajectory(const JointTrajectory&)’:

    /home/lkj/catkin_ws/src/move_group_test/src/cartesian.cpp:199:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘actionlib::SimpleActionClient<moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryAction_<std::allocator<void> > >::sendGoal(moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryAction&)’
   ac.sendGoal(goal);
                   ^
In file included from /home/lkj/catkin_ws/src/move_group_test/src/cartesian.cpp:9:0:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h:316:6: note: candidate: void actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::sendGoal(const Goal&, actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::SimpleDoneCallback, actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::SimpleActiveCallback, 

actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::SimpleFeedbackCallback) [with ActionSpec = moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryAction_<std::allocator<void> >; actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::Goal = moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryGoal_<std::allocator<void> >; actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::SimpleDoneCallback = boost::function<void(const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&)>; typename ActionSpec::_action_result_type::_result_type = moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> >; actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::SimpleActiveCallback = boost::function<void()>; actionlib::SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::SimpleFeedbackCallback = boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr<const moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryFeedback_<std::allocator<void> > >&)>; typename ActionSpec::_action_feedback_type::_feedback_type = moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryFeedback_<std::allocator<void> >]
 void SimpleActionClient<ActionSpec>::sendGoal(const Goal& goal,

      ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h:316:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryAction {aka moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryAction_<std::allocator<void> >}’ to ‘const Goal& {aka const moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryGoal_<std::allocator<void> >&}’
move_group_test/CMakeFiles/cartesian.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'move_group_test/CMakeFiles/cartesian.dir/src/cartesian.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [move_group_test/CMakeFiles/cartesian.dir/src/cartesian.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5647: recipe for target 'move_group_test/CMakeFiles/cartesian.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [move_group_test/CMakeFiles/cartesian.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

so why there is no matching function of sendGoal()??

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260765/%5Bkinetic-actionlib%5Dno-matching-function-for-call--ac.sendgoal(goal);/) by [kaijianliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29662/kaijianliu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbeck28](https://answers.ros.org/users/28876/jbeck28/) on 2018-05-17**:
Not sure if you ever figured this out, but I have the exact same issue.

**Comment by [songshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/39672/songshan/) on 2019-02-20**:
Have you found the reason or any solution? Would be appreciate to get your response on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a tricky one. Remove the word 'Action' from moveit_msgs::ExecuteTrajectoryActionGoal.

---

Originally posted by [troniak](https://answers.ros.org/users/36036/troniak/) with karma: 56 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4